# Difference between 'Go to a movie' and 'Go for a movie'

Tags: word-choice

I've googled *go for a movie* and I think that it is as same as *go to a movie* but it is less used. What is the difference in these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go has different meanings.

(1) Go to a movie.

[Definition 2](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/go): *to move or travel, especially with someone else, to a particular place or in order to be present at an event*

The idea of travel is included.

Other verbs-of-motion can be substituted:

> walk to a movie; swim to a movie; run to a movie; roller skate to a
>   movie; hop on one leg to a movie; crawl to a movie.

(2) Go for a movie.

Idiom: to choose to attend something

How about going for a movie? equals How about choosing to attend a movie?

(Note: this does not mean How about choosing a particular movie to attend.)

How about going for a fashion show?  equals How about choosing to attend (go to) a fashion show?

Other verbs-of-motion may not be substituted:

> *walk for a movie; *swim for a movie; *crawl for a movie

From *The Great Gatsby*:

> Jordan suggests they go for a movie as Daisy signals them to pull alongside the coupé. She asks where they should go and Jordan again suggests the movies.

go for a movie = choose to go to a movie, instead of something esle

---

This is also *not* the same usage as such common phrases as:

> go for a drive;   go for a walk;   go for a drink;   go for a swim

While you can change them to:

> go driving;   go walking;   go drinking;   go swimming

but you can't really say

> go movieing

Comment: "Do a movie" means "play in a movie"? "Going for a fashion show" means "presenting oneself in a fashion show"?

Comment: "do a movie" means "go to a movie." (This is a use of _do_ that you might not be familiar with, so I will edit my answer.) Let's do a movie! Let's go to a movie! _going for a fashion show_ means _choosing to go to (attend) a fashion show._ In this example, _fashion show_ is parallel to _movie_ in _go for a movie_.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to discuss another possible context that hasn't been mentioned. "Go to a movie" is so much more popular because it is the standard way of saying you are seeing a movie.

For example, "I'm going to (go see) a movie tonight." You would never say "I'm going for a movie tonight."

So, when and why do we use "Go for a movie"? There's a phrase in English to express a desire for something: "I could go for X."

For example:

"I could really go for an ice cream right now." or "I could go for a nap."

This means, X sounds really good to me right now.

I would imagine "Go for a movie" being used in the following context:

"What do you want to do tonight?"

"I could go for a movie."

This is actually the only situation in which I can imagine using "Go for a movie." Another answer mentions the question "How about going for a movie?" I don't think this is wrong, but I've never heard before.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather avoid saying "go for a movie" if you are suggesting to someone let's "watch a movie".

But when asked where are you heading off to, to say I am "going to a movie" is appropriate. It infers I am heading to watch a movie.